# Light wave equation - normalized?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, waves

What is the logic between the first and second equations for the electric field? How did they do it and why do we need the x and y components to be 1 over root 2?

[image]

[image]

Comment: $5\,\sqrt {2}=5\cdot \dfrac {\sqrt {2}\cdot \sqrt {2}}{\sqrt {2}}=\dfrac {10}{\sqrt {2}}$

Comment: Just pull out a factor of 10. There is no need to do this, but it makes the equation look nicer.